# Comparing two identical elements in Django doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run some if statements in a Django template I'm writing. Here's the code:

```
{% for object in managers %}
    {{ request.user.username }}
    {{ object.manager }}
    {% if request.user.username == object.manager %}
       You are on the list!
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I run this code while logged in as a user who is a member of objects.manager, I see the following:

username
username

But nothing in the if statement appears. If both values are identical, why wouldn't it be working? I know it's not the most elegant way to do this but at the moment I only have access to the template files and I'm trying to get something up quickly :)

Thank you!

Comment: maybe the object.manager is a foreignkey (int) and request.user.username is a str. Try {% if request.user == object.manager %}

Comment: Can I post my answer?

Comment: please do! I'll mark it as solved and give you a star when it's posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object.manager is a foreignkey (int) and your request.user.username is a (str). To make it equal use both foreign keys.

```
{% if request.user == object.manager %}
```

You can also use request.user.username. Like for example:

```
{% if request.user.username == object.manager.username %}
```

Pattern:

```
(int) == (int)
('str') == ('str')
(FK or PK) == (int)
(FK or PK) == (FK or PK)
```